# Do liquids in tall containers or wide containers cool faster?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

Given two containers of equal volume, one tall and thin, one short and wide, containing the same liquid at the same temperature, pressure, etc... which one would cool faster?

Answer (score 1):

In general the container having the greater surface area to volume ratio will cool faster. That’s because, all other things being equal, the rate of heat transfer is proportional to the surface area of an object, particularly for convective and radiant heat transfer. So for a given volume, all other things being equal, the more surface area the greater the rate of heat transfer.

Hope this helps